# Silex deployement IIS

Tags: php, symfony, iis, twig, silex

i'm working on a Silex project and i have this error 500 that i cant figureout how to fix it.

the project is located on a shared drive (a file server) behind another server with IIS and php 5.5.
I dont have any prob on my local server.

The error:

```
string(2710) "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Invalid resource provided: "1.2"; Errors: [WARNING 1549] failed to load external entity "file://///PASE-CFG-PP1/IIS_CONTENT/MYPROJECT/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/schema/dic/xliff-core/xml.xsd" (in n/a - line 0, column 0)
[WARNING 3084] Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'file://///PASE-CFG-PP1/IIS_CONTENT/MYPROJECT/vendor/symfony/translation/Loader/schema/dic/xliff-core/xml.xsd'. Skipping the import. (in in_memory_buffer - line 33, column 0)
[ERROR 3004] attribute use (unknown), attribute 'ref': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang' does not resolve to a(n) attribute declaration. (in in_memory_buffer - line 1661, column 0)
...
...
```

Is it a missconfiguration of my own ? or maybe symfony which doesn't handle unc path or something like that ? 
and how to fix it ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Php (DOMDocument) can validate loaded xml with the defined xsd's. Internally it parses the xml and when it sees a xsd reference for validation, that xsd is retrieved and used to validate the xml.

The translation loader component is probably loading xml and can't find the xsd to validate it. Is php allowed to access the file on the fileSystem (file permissions)?
If you want to be sure, try `file_get_contents()` on the specific file from php.

If this isn't the issue you have 2 options. These will ignore the problem and not solve it:
 1. Disable xml errors before loading translation.
 2. Disable the translation component

The XmlUtils code from Symfony can be a good reference:
https://github.com/symfony/config/blob/master/Util/XmlUtils.php

They have had issues with validation:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10493